# Change rabbitmq default port

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to change rabbitmq to another port,but in some low port it can't be start.for example 79 or 54 or any port under ~300.It can be started at port which is higher than 1000

Rabbitmq configuration file:

```
[{rabbit,[{loopback_users,[]},{tcp_listeners,[72]}]}].
```

captured tcp ports:

```
# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3310              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9602/clamd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      10224/nginx         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1938/epmd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1073/sendmail       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50683               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      7393/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      29876/beam          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      5206/php-fpm        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      15475/mongod
```

logs:

```
#tailf /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_err 

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()

#tailf /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_log

   {bad_return,
       {{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},
        {'EXIT',
            {rabbit,failure_during_boot,
                {could_not_start_tcp_listener,{"::",72}}}}}}}
```

Comment: Check your user permissions. The username being used to launch it might not have rights to start on some of the typical IANA-assigned ports. Try launching with sudo as a test.

Comment: @BrianKelly I tried to start it by root user.